# Rename MYSQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any simple way to rename the database using PHP? I just want to rename the database from 'mydb' to 'mydb_deleted' using PHP.

*-( I don't want to create new database and then drop the old one) .*

Comment: @AnkurTiwari he is talking about renaming database not renaming table

Comment: If you want to do it in PHP, you can consider writing a function that will ultimately run a query to rename your table .

Comment: is there any query to rename database?

Comment: use php myadmin->operations->Rename Database to..